# Do you think it is better for people to live in a house or in an apartment?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence correct?
I think the question should be "Which do you think is better, to live in a house or in an apartment?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are contrasting the sentence in the title,

> Do you think it is better for people to live in a house, or in an apartment?

with

> Which do you think is better, to live in a house or in an apartment?

Either is correct for this idea, but note the addition of a necessary comma in the first sentence, after the word "house". Without the comma, it could be asking whether it's better to live in a house or in an apartment, or outdoors on the street.